# Python: How to accept input from user and then redirect console output

Tags: python-3.x, stdout

I have a usecase, where my Python code takes an input from user, let's say a filename and then print the content of it in console. I am unable to understand how I can redirect the output of console to another file `output.txt`
Let's say, if I pass below command on console:

`python test.py > output.txt`

For obvious reason, control get redirected to file buffer and console remains blank and idle.
Can someone please suggest, how such usecase can be handled such that user input is asked and then all output of python code is redirected to `output.txt`

**test.py**

```
file_name = input("Enter filename:")
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        list_of_words_in_line = line.split()
        print(list_of_words_in_line)
f.close()
```

I am sorry, if this question is very basic for someone.

Comment: Do you mean write to specified file instead of writing to sys.stdout?

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite `sys.stdout`

```
import sys 
file_name = input("Enter File Name:")
sys.stdout = open(file_name, "w")
print("HAHAHAHAH")
sys.stdout.close()
```

You can re-access the original `stdout` by resetting it - `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`

Comment: I want to redirect all console output to a file, which is provided in command line argument.

Comment: Yes, that's what this does - did you try?

Comment: Your code, asks for a filename from user and then redirects print statement to this file.

Question is about: passing command `python test.py > output.txt` in console. And a in console it should ask: "Enter filename" and then redirects all output to `output.txt`